# How do I forge a gem worth 1,000,000+ gold?

Tags: infinity-blade-2

You earn the *Cold Fusion* achievement in Infinity Blade 2 by forging a gem worth 1,000,000 or more gold.  How do I do this?  Do I continue forging gems until I get to 1,000,000+, or is there some alchemy involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max value of a gem is 500,000 gold, so you can't ever forge a gem worth 1,000,000 gold or more. The text of the achievement is misleading. It should read "Forge gems worth a total of 1,000,000 gold or more". So the game sums up the value of each forged gem. When that sum is greater than 1,000,000, you get the achievement.

Answer (score 2):

When you forge three gems, you have to pay a certain amount of cash after a certain amount of time. After paying one million cash to forge gems, you will get the achievement. So no, it doesn't have to be 1 million at once.

A good strategy is to buy the most expensive gem and forge it with two low priced gems until you have payed over a million gold.

Comment: You're mostly correct. The text of the achievement is misleading.  It should read "Forge gems worth a total of 1,000,000 gold or more". The max value of a gem is 500,000 gold, so the game sums up the value of each forged gem.  When that sum is greater than 1,000,000, you get the achievement.

Comment: @splatteredbits With the 500k gem and two cheap ones, you can forge a new gem which you can then use with other cheap gems. So yea